# Gulp и css-файлы

Tags: css, gulp

Как сделать, чтобы Gulp "выплёвывал" минифицированную и обычную версии CSS? Сейчас выплёвывает только минифицированную. gulpfile.js ниже...

```js
var gulp           = require('gulp'),
  gutil          = require('gulp-util' ),
  sass           = require('gulp-sass'),
  browserSync    = require('browser-sync'),
  concat         = require('gulp-concat'),
  uglify         = require('gulp-uglify'),
  cleanCSS       = require('gulp-clean-css'),
  rename         = require('gulp-rename'),
  del            = require('del'),
  imagemin       = require('gulp-imagemin'),
  cache          = require('gulp-cache'),
  autoprefixer   = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
  ftp            = require('vinyl-ftp'),
  notify         = require("gulp-notify"),
  rsync          = require('gulp-rsync');

// Скрипты проекта

gulp.task('common-js', function() {
 return gulp.src([
  'app/js/common.js',
  ])
 .pipe(concat('common.min.js'))
 .pipe(uglify())
 .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js'));
});

gulp.task('js', ['common-js'], function() {
 return gulp.src([
  'app/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
  'app/libs/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.js',
  'app/js/common.min.js', // Всегда в конце
  ])
 .pipe(concat('scripts.min.js'))
 // .pipe(uglify()) // Минимизировать весь js (на выбор)
 .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js'))
 .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
 browserSync({
  server: {
   baseDir: 'app'
  },
  notify: false,
  // tunnel: true,
  // tunnel: "projectmane", //Demonstration page: http://projectmane.localtunnel.me
 });
});

gulp.task('sass', function() {
 return gulp.src('app/sass/**/*.sass')
 .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'expand'}).on("error", notify.onError()))
 .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min', prefix : ''}))
 .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions']))
 .pipe(cleanCSS()) // Опционально, закомментировать при отладке
 .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
 .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['sass', 'js', 'browser-sync'], function() {
 gulp.watch('app/sass/**/*.sass', ['sass']);
 gulp.watch(['libs/**/*.js', 'app/js/common.js'], ['js']);
 gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('imagemin', function() {
 return gulp.src('app/img/**/*')
 .pipe(cache(imagemin()))
 .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img')); 
});

gulp.task('build', ['removedist', 'imagemin', 'sass', 'js'], function() {

 var buildFiles = gulp.src([
  'app/*.html',
  'app/.htaccess',
  ]).pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));

 var buildCss = gulp.src([
  'app/css/main.min.css',
  ]).pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));

 var buildJs = gulp.src([
  'app/js/scripts.min.js',
  ]).pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));

 var buildFonts = gulp.src([
  'app/fonts/**/*',
  ]).pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts'));

});

gulp.task('deploy', function() {

 var conn = ftp.create({
  host:      'hostname.com',
  user:      'username',
  password:  'userpassword',
  parallel:  10,
  log: gutil.log
 });

 var globs = [
 'dist/**',
 'dist/.htaccess',
 ];
 return gulp.src(globs, {buffer: false})
 .pipe(conn.dest('/path/to/folder/on/server'));

});

gulp.task('rsync', function() {
 return gulp.src('dist/**')
 .pipe(rsync({
  root: 'dist/',
  hostname: 'username@yousite.com',
  destination: 'yousite/public_html/',
  archive: true,
  silent: false,
  compress: true
 }));
});

gulp.task('removedist', function() { return del.sync('dist'); });
gulp.task('clearcache', function () { return cache.clearAll(); });

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можете использовать gulp-sassbeautify, который не сжимает код, после чего использовать sass-gulp, который уже сожмет при билде.

Comment: Чёт я не нашёл в файле .pipe(modificate())

Comment: Это для примера, вы вставляете вместо него ваш плагин (минификатор или ренеймер...).